Would like to learn how to restore APFS SSD's that have been corrupted
I have three or four Samsung 860 SSD drives, with APFS containers that have gotten corrupted in one way or another (by my efforts to load linux, or to do other things).
It appears that I need to learn how to do things the correct way.
I know that DiskWarrior won't do it.
I've at last been able to make a bootable Ubuntu USB drive (since I was shown how to do enableGOP by flashing the firmware on the computer and the GPU). That allowed the Radeon RX580 to give me a boot picker screen - without that, it is very difficult to choose a Ubuntu drive on startup.
Ubuntu has GParted and TestDisk. And from what I now know, neither of those two will help me to fix the corrupted drives.
However, I have read of people on this group who do have the knowledge to get the terminal to give the necessary information, to interpret it correctly, and then - in at least some instances - to repair things.
I want to learn that. Otherwise, I'm likely to keep coming back and asking questions for the same thing, over and over.
What are good sources where I can learn what I need to know. I'm willing to do the work, and I'm willing to help others, once I have learned.
I will be glad to answer any questions that help lead to solutions for the problem(s) that I have.
Thanks for any assistance.

Welcome to AskDifferent. The first step on your learning journey could be to look at existing questions about SSD/APFS repair, and at the commands used in the answers there. This should get you off the ground, you can then ask specific questions based on things you tried when your are stuck.

Also, which Mac do you have, with which version of macOS?

I have a Mac Pro 5,1, upgraded from a 4,1, running High Sierra, Mojave, Catalina, Sonoma, Windows 10, and Ubuntu. Learning OpenCore manually from the tutorial on  MacRumors.com Forums for OpenCore. I am running - mostly 2 Tb - Samsung EVO 860 SSD's. The GPU is a Radeon Sapphire RX580 with the firmware updated to EnableGOP - to give me bootpicker screen on startup if I use the option key. It also allows for the use of the other command keys on startup.

I will start to review and learn from the SSD posts and the APFS posts. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

I learned that an APFS drive requires more throughput capacity than is normally provided by a standard SATA controller. Would that be correct? I have a Mac 5,1 with 4 2Tb EVO 860 SSD drives (one in each drive bay). Those are listed as being SATA. I have had virtually no problems HFS+ formatted drives. Mojave can be set up that way on an SSD if CCC is used. Should I try an NVMe controller and drive instead? I have a Radeon RX580 installed.
